# R: Most efficient way for file-backed storage of large sparse 3-way tensor or sparse augmented matrix

Tags: r, dplyr, sparse-matrix, tensor, r-bigmemory

I would like to have an efficient framework in R for doing file-backed storage of a large 3-way tensor of long integers (15000 (time dimension) x 500000 (2nd dimension) x 500 (sample, 3d dimension)), using as a row/time dimension augmented matrix (i.e. using a 15000*500000 x 500 matrix), and I need functionality to efficiently retrieve particular sections of this matrix for in-memory processing as well as update particular sections after processing. For dense matrices, I can use the `bigmatrix` package for this, but in my final application the matrices are sparse (with ca. 99% zeros), and as I understand `bigmatrix` currently does not support sparse matrices. Does anyone know of any other options I could use for this in R? (packages `ff` and [dplyr backed with an on-disk database](https://db.rstudio.com/dplyr/) I understand also don't support sparse matrices or tensors for the moment) Any thoughts?

Example code for the dense tensor/augmented matrix case (but which would need to also work for sparse tensors/matrices that are 1000 bigger) is

```
# example problem size
NRows = 15000 # time dimension
NCols = 500 # 2nd dimension, 1000x larger & sparse in final application 
NSamples = 20 # sample dimension, 500 in reality, testing with 20 here

# just filling with a constant integer here, in reality data is read in from netcdf file
# in final application data will be 1000x larger & sparse, with 99% zeros

getsamplematrix = function(r=NRows,c=NCols) matrix(1L, nrow=r, ncol=c) 
### 1. Using bigmemory as backend
library(bigmemory)

## step 1: store tensor in row/time dimension augmented bigmemory matrix
putdata = function (NRows, NCols, NSamples) {
  data = big.matrix(NRows*NSamples, NCols, type = "integer",
    backingfile = "data.bin", descriptorfile = "data.desc",
    backingpath = getwd() )

  for (i in 1:NSamples) {
    data[(1+(i-1)*NRows):(i*NRows), 1:NCols] = getsamplematrix(r = NRows, c = NCols)
  }
  attr(data, "NRows") = NRows
  return(data)
}
system.time(data <- putdata(NRows,NCols,NSamples)) # 23.28 s for 20 matrices


## step 2: get subset of time slices from all samples and store this in 3-way tensor/array S (for in-memory processing)
getsubtensor = function(data, timeindices, cols, samples) { 
  S = array(dim=c(length(timeindices),length(cols),length(samples))) # preallocate array
  nrows = attr(data,"NRows")
  for (i in samples) { 
    S[timeindices,cols,i] = data[((1+(i-1)*nrows):(i*nrows))[timeindices],cols]
  }
  return(S) }
# example: get time indices 1:100 from all samples
system.time(S <- getsubtensor(data, 1:100, 1:NCols, 1:NSamples)) # 0.04 s
dim(S)


## step 3: update subtensor S at given positions in original disk-mapped data after some processing
updatesubtensor = function(data, S, timeindices, cols, samples) { 
  nrows = attr(data,"NRows")
  for (i in samples) { 
    data[((1+(i-1)*nrows):(i*nrows))[timeindices],cols] = S[timeindices,cols,i] 
  }
  return(data) }
S2 <- S*2L # example, processing would be done here
system.time(data <- updatesubtensor(data, S2, 1:100, 1:NCols, 1:NSamples)) # 0.17s
```

Comment: What is a `cdf` file?

Comment: Ha that's just a format that's read in using R package ncdf4 - but that shouldn't matter for the problem of how to store the matrices - basically you could just assume I'm dealing with random matrices or something...

Comment: Maybe adding a reproducible example would help us helping you.

Comment: I'll add a bit of code to produce at least some matrices no probs!

Comment: Added a reproducible example for bigmemory now...

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution? What would you like to improve?

Comment: For your size of data (even with `NSamples = 500`), this takes only 4 min on my laptop with only 8GB of RAM. Most of the time is taken filling the matrix with random numbers.

Comment: I rewrote my question to make it clearer - main problem I have is that my problem size for high-res data would be 1000x larger and would have sparse matrices (with 99% zeros) and that bigmemory doesn't support sparse matrices

Comment: So, it will take too much RAM even with a `dgCMatrix`? By the way, I tried something sometimes ago to use sparse data with bigmemory: https://github.com/privefl/spBigMatrix. Finally, I think that the best way would be to use a list (for each sample) of `dgCMatrix` (possible stored in rdsfiles).

Comment: Yes indeed (except on very high end machines, but I would like to make it work also for mid-range PCs)! Thanks for the link to spBigMatrix - I'll look into it, and also try the option of storing dgCMatrices in rdsfiles!